# Как склеить зеркала сайта

Tags: seo

У меня в вебмастере при добавлении сайта в формате https://site.ru возникает предупреждение что это не основное зеркало сайта, а основным зеркалом является site.ru, как мне склеить зеркала так, что бы основным оказалось https://site.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Гугл склеивает зеркала когда получает по неосновным код 301, а по основному 200, это настраивается с помощью файла .htaccess, вот пример:

```
RewriteEngine On
# www переадресовывать на без www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.proflist-ryzan\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://proflist-ryzan.ru//$1 [R=301,L]

# если по порту 80 (http), то переадресуем на ssl
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://proflist-ryzan.ru/$1 [R=301,L]  

# если по порту 443 (https), то переадресуем на http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:80/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Яндексу нужно ещё прописать в файле robots.txt директиву host, вот так:

```
Host: https://proflist-ryzan.ru
```

Если помог, примите ответ пожалуйста!)